# SQL copy sum of 2 varchars to to new table

Tags: sql, sum, aggregate, casting

tis my first question so sorry if its not well structured, I have looked for the answer for a while but no joy so here goes..

basically I have 20 columns and want to take the result of adding columns (a+b) (b+c) etc and make this the value of my new columns,

when i do a simple select statement the values appear as expected but i cant seem to get them to appear into a new table

the columns are varchars

this is one of the 20 select queries

((accidentlogs.before_T18/16-accidentlogs.before_T19/16)/21.954),

It seems like such an easy function and it probably is but stick a fork in me on this one

Comment: First, you can select the code in your question and use ctrl+K for better readability. Second, since they are varchars should i assume you want to concatenate strings? Or do you have numbers stored in varchars which you want to cast and then perhaps add/sub etc.

Comment: Varchars are string data types.  When you say **add** do you mean concatenate, as in `'A' + 'B' = 'AB'` or are you storing numeric data in a varchar field?

Comment: Can you post your complete query and table structure? Should be an INSERT statement i think.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the result of a SELECT Statement as a value for an INSERT Statement. The exact syntax may vary for the SQL Dialect you use (Oracle, Postgres, MySql...)

This is the code for postgres:

```
INSERT INTO table (field1, field2...) SELECT 'value1', 'value2'...
```